# How to get the value(from inputing) of s:textfield without s:form and send the value to the relative action

Tags: struts2, action, textfield

```
<s:textfield label="input" id="book" name="bookNum"></s:textfield>
<s:a href="buyBookAction">buy</s:a>
```

I want to get the value of `textfield` tag and send to the relative action.

Comment: Why without a form ? This smells of [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... btw if you don't want a form, use querystring parameters

Comment: because the jsp have two <s:a> one links to buyNow.action,the other to addTocart.ction

Comment: 1) You can submit the same form to two different actions with two submit buttons (or two <s:a> ), otherwise 2) you can read the value with Javascript and append it to s:a parameters (querystring)

Comment: @Andrea Ligios    ok!   I try to read the value with Javascript...Thanks you!!